# How to view phoenix routes in iex?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How do i view the output of a route in `iex`?

I know i can do this with `mix Phoenix.routes` but would like to do this interactively.

Here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
iex -S Phoenix.server

mymodel_path
```

this gives me this error:

```
** (CompileError) iex:2: undefined function mymodel_path/0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the url/path helpers are compiled into functions in the module `YourApp.Router.Helpers`. You can import it and call with the same arguments as you would in your templates (you would probably pass `conn` as the first argument but since we don't have a `conn` in the `iex` session, you can pass `YourApp.Endpoint` instead):

```
iex(1)> import YourApp.Router.Helpers
nil
iex(2)> page_path(YourApp.Endpoint, :index)
"/"
iex(3)> task_path(YourApp.Endpoint, :show, 1)
"/tasks/1"
```

(I have a `resources "/tasks", TaskController` in this project.)

Comment: Why does that work? I'd love to learn more. cc @Dogbert

Answer (score 12):

```
iex> Mix.Tasks.Phoenix.Routes.run ''                                              
page_path  GET   /           YourApp.PageController :index                                
user_path  GET   /users      YourApp.UserController :index                               
user_path  GET   /users/new  YourApp.UserController :new                                  
user_path  GET   /users/:id  YourApp.UserController :show                               
user_path  POST  /users      YourApp.UserController :create
```

---

**Phoenix 1.3 update**: `mix phoenix.routes is deprecated. Use phx.routes instead.` That is:

```
iex(7)> Mix.Tasks.Phx.Routes.run ''
 page_path  GET  /       HelloWeb.PageController :index
hello_path  GET  /hello  HelloWeb.HelloController :index
```

Comment: This was not what the OP asked but it was precisely what I was looking for when I googled this title.

Comment: @jaysoifer Exactly! I found it more useful actually!! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
YourApp.Web.Router.__routes__()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the appropriate documentation for your requiement at the official docs here - http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/routing#section-path-helpers

Assuming your app name is `HelloPhoenix`

```
iex> import HelloPhoenix.Router.Helpers
iex> alias HelloPhoenix.Endpoint
iex> user_path(Endpoint, :index)
"/users"

iex> user_path(Endpoint, :show, 17)
"/users/17"

iex> user_path(Endpoint, :new)
"/users/new"

iex> user_path(Endpoint, :create)
"/users"
```

Answer (score 0):

for umbrella app you should use

```
Mix.Tasks.Phx.Routes.run([YourApp.Web.Router])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume: Project name = Mango 
I have created a Registration Controller (:new,:create) and a CategoryController(:show)

```
from iex:

alias MangoWeb.Router.Helpers , as: Routes 
alias MangoWeb.Endpoint 

Routes.page_path(Endpoint,:index)
"/"  

Routes.category_path(Endpoint,:show,17) 
"/categories/17"

Routes.registration_path(Endpoint,:new)
"/register" 

Routes.registration_path(Endpoint,:create)
"/register" 

Routes.category_path(Endpoint,:show,"fruit")
"/categories/fruit"

Routes.page_url(Endpoint,:index)
"http://localhost:4000/"

Routes.category_url(Endpoint,:show,"fruit")
"http://localhost:4000/categories/fruit"  

Routes.category_url(Endpoint,:show,"vegetables")
"http://localhost:4000/categories/vegetables"

Routes.registration_url(Endpoint,:new)
"http://localhost:4000/register"

Routes.registration_url(Endpoint,:create)
"http://localhost:4000/register" 
etc.
```